# Populating a dropdown list with a stored procedure (showing usernames) then showing the users full name instead of username - slow

Tags: c#, asp.net, dropdown

I have a drop down -

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="OriginatorDropDown" DataTextField="User"
DataValueField="User" runat="server" CssClass="form-control">
      <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="" Value="" />  </asp:DropDownList>
```

And I am populating it on the page load. However it is awfully slow..
i only have about 30 people in the list, it shouldnt be this slow. Any
ideas please?

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         if (!IsPostBack)
         {
             GetUsers();
         }

     }


     private void GetUsers()
     {
         OriginatorDropDown.Items.Clear();
         OriginatorDropDown.DataSource = GetUserData();
         OriginatorDropDown.DataBind();

         foreach (ListItem ltItem in OriginatorDropDown.Items)
         {
             if (ltItem.Text != String.Empty)
             {
                 using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
                 {
                     UserPrincipal up = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, IdentityType.SamAccountName
,ltItem.Text);
                     if (up != null)
                     {
                         ltItem.Text = up.DisplayName;
                     }

                 }
             }
         }
     }

     public DataSet GetUserData()
     {

         using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ElectronicPayments))
         {
             //Get status descriptions
             using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetAllUsers", myConnection))
             {
                 cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;


                 SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                 DataSet user = new DataSet();



                 myConnection.Open();
                 da.Fill(user);

                 return user;
             }
         }
     }
```

Comment: It's slow because you're making an AD user lookup query for every user. The full name should already be stored in the database. If you use WebForms and its Membership and User Profile providers, the info should already be there. You shouldn't have to execute an AD query every time you use a user's name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible your context creation at each iteration may takes time. Could you try this :

```
    private void GetUsers()
     {
         OriginatorDropDown.Items.Clear();
         OriginatorDropDown.DataSource = GetUserData();
         OriginatorDropDown.DataBind();


using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
         foreach (ListItem ltItem in OriginatorDropDown.Items)
         {
             if (ltItem.Text != String.Empty)
             {


                     UserPrincipal up = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, IdentityType.SamAccountName
,ltItem.Text);
                     if (up != null)
                     {
                         ltItem.Text = up.DisplayName;
                     }


             }
         }
     }
```